# How do I properly load the jQuery fullcalendar plugin in a hidden div

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the jQuery tools tabs to divide my page into tabs. One of those tabs contain a jQuery Fullcalendar. Because I load JavaScript last in the page for speed and to avoid flash of unstyled content, I hide the initially unseen tabs using display:none. When doing this, the fullcalendar doesn't render properly. It shows the proper buttons, but until I press the today-button, no calendar is shown. If I allow it to render into a visible div, it displays properly.

I can work around this using the tab-select events to render the calendar or by moving the calendar and tab scripts to the head, but I'd rather if there was a more proper solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is load the data after the link is clicked, not entirely sure but i think the issue is that the height is not set correctly after the data is loaded so it only shows the top part.

What i have done and worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendareventlink").click ( function(){
      loadCalendar();
    });
});
function loadCalendar(){
  //Do your data loading here
}

<a href="" id="calendareventlink">View Calendar</a>
```

Comment: This is actually more or less what I did as well in the end, binding it to the tab show event of my tabs, works pretty well, even though it feels like a hack :)

Answer (score 35):

When the div is hidden, fullCalendar doesn't know what size it should render itself, so you just need to call the `render` function after you know that the *div is visible*.

Attach it to the show event or whatever:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I ended up doing, see my comment to the first answer :)

Comment: Much prefer this solution rather than having to re-call the entire init script (I always dislike running scripts multiple times if there's some sort of a reload, refresh or in this case a render option available)

Comment: If your using React, make sure to set state of any variable involving calendar size **before** calling calendar.render()

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is ancient, but it came out first while I was searching for the solution for the same problem.
For some reason [the proposed solution with `render`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755767/536172) doesn't work in some specific cases (if the inactive tab is loaded with calendar entries), so I had to `refetchEvents`.

The code is as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the tab call something like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'); // Force the calendar to render
```

Answer (score 2):

you must using javascript to set display none fullcalendar

something like this:

```
                document.getElementById("test").style.display="none";
```

then it looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='bigcalendar.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.8.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='bigcalendar.js'></script>   

    <script type='text/javascript'>


        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#bigCalendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: false,
                events: [{"id":111,"title":"Event1","start":"2012-11-10","url":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"},{"id":222,"title":"Event2","start":"2012-11-20","end":"2012-11-22","url":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"}]
            });

            document.getElementById("test").style.display="none";
        });





        function closeEventDetails(){

            $("#test").hide("fast");
        }



        function showBigCalendar(){

            $("#test").show("fast");

            //                $('#bigCalendar').fullCalendar( 'render' )

        }



        $(document).ready(function() {
        });

    </script>

    <style type='text/css'>

        body {
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

        #bigcalendar {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>


    <!--zobrazenie velkeho kalendara-->

    <button onclick="showBigCalendar();"  >open</button>
    <button  onclick="closeEventDetails();">close</button>

    <div id="test" ><div id="bigCalendar" ></div></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with the having to click the "today" button to make the calendar actually appear in a jQueryUI tab. I was able to solve the problem completely by initializing the tabs AFTER I initialized the calendar. I am, however, doing this in the head of the document, and calling all other js just before the close of the body tag. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call .resize() for any parent/ancestor element of the calendar -- when you know the calendar is visible ;)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the fullcalendar.min.js to the latest version (3.9.0) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue using [easyappointments](https://github.com/alextselegidis/easyappointments) project, the solution was to call **fullCalendar('render')** , within a callback function after the next wizard div is showed:

*JQuery Code*:

```
 // Display the next step tab (uses jquery animation effect).
        var nextTabIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-step_index')) + 1;
  $('#button-next-1').click(function () {

         $(this).parents().eq(1).hide('fade', function () {
                 /* some code */
             $('#wizard-frame-' + nextTabIndex).show('fade');
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
         });
    });
```

*Html Code*:

```
           <div id="wizard-frame-1" class="wizard-frame">

                 <div class="frame-container"  style="margin-top: 20px!important">/*some code*/</div>




                <div class="modal-footer fixedFooter p-l-10 p-r-10">
                           <button type="button" id="button-next-1" class="btn button-next btn-primary"
                            data-step_index="1">
                                     <?= lang('next') ?>
                                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
                            </button>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

have you tried display:hidden instead of display:none?

No idea whether it will work, but something worth trying.

Comment: I think you mean `visiblity: hidden;` - this worked for me with a position of absolute. In fact without this `fullCalendar('render')` didn't work at all.
Bit dirty, but... `$('#calendar').css({ position: 'relative', visibility: 'visible' }).fullCalendar('render');`